# Wagtail app on Django on FastCGI on shared hosting

Tags: python, django, unhandled-exception, wagtail

I'm using A Small Orange's shared hosting, and have set up Django to run in Virtualenv with FastCGI as per their tutorial.

I'm trying to setup Wagtail, a Django-variant CMS. 
Am assuming it I run it as an Django app within Django in a virtualenv interfaced with FastCGI. But I get an "Unhanded Expection was thrown by the application" when I run.

my dispatch.fcgi file read:

```
#!/home/username/.env/env/bin/python

import sys
import os

sys.path.insert(0, '/home/username/.env/lib/python2.6/site-packages')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myproj.settings'

from django.core.servers.fastcgi import runfastcgi
runfastcgi(method="threaded", daemonize="false")
```

my .htaccess file read:

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dispatch.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

My file structure is:

```
~/website/myproj # created using django-admin.py startproj
~/website/myproj/wagtailwebsite #created using manage.py startapp
```

Wagtailwebsite's settings.py and urls.py files are edited as in the [Wagtail tutorial](https://gist.github.com/tomdyson/8974456)

Unfortunately I cannot run it on a local server to test due to restricted permissions on a shared hosting.

Am a major noob at this but if you see Wagtail's UI you'll know why I'm throwing myself into the deep end. Do let me know if I'm providing enough information!

Comment: update: running ./dispatch.fcgi brings up `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI application 'wagtailweb.wsgi.application' could not be loaded; Error importing module wagtailweb.wsgi: "No module named wagtailweb.wsgi"` My hosting makes it compulsory to use FCGI so I'm not sure what to do with the wsgi module here? Can I just delete it?